# Application insights: SQL Dependency result code "-2"

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, sqldependency

This is what I get in ~20 out of ~2M SQL dependency AI registrations.

[image: Azure portal screenshot]

Apparently this result code does not appear in sys.messages, since all message id's in there are positive.

Also I can't seem to find any stack trace information on this error. It seems to be a timeout or general transient error (handled by Polly from my side), but either way it's registered under dependencies and not exceptions.

Does anybody know what this error is and where I can find more information regarding all possible SQL dependency errors I might get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have submitted this issue to app insights team [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/304), and just get feedback:

```
 -2 means Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the 
operation or the server is not responding. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2).
```

The Sql Exception number is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc645611%28v%3Dsql.105%29).

And if you have any concerns, please comment at that [thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/304). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan for your help.